# How to append two dimensional arrays corner by corner

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**Question:**

I have n two dimensional square arrays of arbitrary order. For sake of simplicity let's say I have 3 two dimensional arrays A, B, C with orders 3×3, 4×4, 2×2 respectively. Here:

```
   [[a a a]      [[b b b b]     [[c c]  
A=  [a a a]  ,B=  [b b b b] ,C=  [c c]]
    [a a a]]      [b b b b]
                  [b b b b]
```

I know for two dimensional arrays with same number of rows, we can append them very easily (just adding the columns sidewise), but even if these arrays had same number of rows, I don't want them to append sidewise but I want to create from these 3 arrays another two-dimensional square array of order 3+4+2=9, i.e., a `9×9 array`, say, `coll_array`. Here:

```
            [[a a a 0 0 0 0 0 0]
             [a a a 0 0 0 0 0 0]
             [a a a 0 0 0 0 0 0]
             [0 0 0 b b b b 0 0]
coll_array=  [0 0 0 b b b b 0 0]
             [0 0 0 b b b b 0 0]
             [0 0 0 b b b b 0 0]
             [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 c c]
             [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 c c]]
```

Please look at the above array carefully. I know this is not append but *I am not from CS background*, I don't know what it can be called. I
am basically inserting the elements of those 3 arrays in this collective array.

**What I tried:**

`T = len(A)+len(B)+len(C)`

I know I can first initialise a T×T two dimensional array:

```
coll_array=np.array([[0]*T]*T).reshape(T,T)
for i in range(T):
    for j in range(T):
        if (i< len(A)) and (j<len(A)):
           coll_array[i,j]=a  # yes i have same values in the individual arrays, would have been more complex with this method if not.
        elif (i>=len(A)) and (j>=len(A)) and (i<len(A)+len(B)) and (j<len(A)+len(B)):
           coll_array[i,j]=b
        elif (i>=len(A)+len(B)) and (j>=len(A)+len(B)) and (i<len(A)+len(B)+len(C)) and (j<len(A)+len(B)+len(C)):
           coll_array[i,j]=c
        else:
           coll_array[i,j]=0
```

Yes this would work, but the problem is I don't have just 3 two-dimensional square arrays to combine but I have n number of them and n could be very large, for which I need to write n-1 elif statements, requiring a loop or something. I can create dynamic global variables like `lensum1 for len(A)`,  `lensum2 for len(A)+len(B)`,  `lensum10 for len(A)+len(B)+...+ len(L)`. That's not a problem, but writing these many elif statements automatically is the main task.

**Note:** I don't have these arrays names A,B,C etc. But i have another array of these arrays like this: `ind_array= [A B C . . .]` and I might need to assign some global variable name to these arrays like A1,A2, etc. if needed, but it would be better if they can be called directly using `ind_array[0], ind_array[1] etc.`

**About efficiency:**

Of course I would not like my program to check so many if-elif conditions for each `(i,j)`, therefore a method to append these arrays corner to corner is what I need or any other efficient program which can achieve this task.

Thank you. Any help will be appreciated.

Request: Please don't mark this as off-topic or close before I get some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`scipy.linalg.block_diag`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.block_diag.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import block_diag

a = np.full((3,3), "a")
b = np.full((4,4), "b")
c = np.full((2,2), "c")

block_diag(a, b, c)
# or block_diag(*[list_or_arrays])
```

Or make the variable length of square array (as per the comment):

```
ind_array = ["a", "b", "c"]
shape_array = [3, 4, 2]

block_diag(*[np.full((i, i), c) for c, i in zip(ind_array, shape_array)])
```

Output:

```
array([['a', 'a', 'a', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ['a', 'a', 'a', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ['a', 'a', 'a', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'c', 'c'],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'c', 'c']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Wow wow wow..thank you so much sir. I was not aware that some pre existing module in python can have this functionality. There's one more thing though, not part of the question (policy says question should be focussed to one problem so..) but if you can answer I'll be glad.

Comment: The thing is I don't have these individual square arrays, instead, I have `[a b c]` and `[3 4 2]` from which I need to create that `ind_array` @Chris

Comment: Oh..wait..i don't need those individual arrays `A, B, C` or their array `[A B C]` with your program...superrr. Thanks

Comment: ```ind_array = ["a", "b", "c"]
shape_array = [3, 4, 2]

block_diag(*[np.full((i, i), c) for c, i in zip(ind_array, shape_array)])    ```  so I can have n number of elements in this ind_array and shape_array? Also these `a, b, c` are actually one dimensional array with two elements each. I don't have `a`. What I have there is `[m_a, c_a]` so this won't be a problem. Right?

Comment: Yes you may have `n` number of elements, but `ind_array` and `shape_array` must be of equal length. For the second part, I don't get it. Please edit your question with appropriate sample ;)

Comment: Yes of course `ind_array` and `shape array` will have same number of elements. Second part of my question, these a, b, c are not string values, their datatype is array again. I just used these letters to avoid complexity. Consider this: `a=[a1 a2], b=[b1 b2], c=[c1 c2]` Can i replace a, b, c in your program with RHS of these equations respectively?

Comment: So your actual input would be 3-d? If so, no, `block_diag` can only handle up to 2-d

Comment: I have `ind_array=[[a1 a2], [b1 b2], [c1 c2]]` and `shape_array=[3,4,2]` ```[[[a1 a2] [a1 a2] [a1 a2] 0 0 0 0 0 0]
             [[a1 a2] [a1 a2] [a1 a2] 0 0 0 0 0 0]
             [[a1 a2] [a1 a2] [a1 a2] 0 0 0 0 0 0]
             [0 0 0 [b1 b2]  [b1 b2]  [b1 b2]  [b1 b2] 0 0]
             [0 0 0 [b1 b2]  [b1 b2]  [b1 b2]  [b1 b2] 0 0]
             [0 0 0 [b1 b2]  [b1 b2]  [b1 b2]  [b1 b2] 0 0]
             [0 0 0 [b1 b2]  [b1 b2]  [b1 b2]  [b1 b2] 0 0]
             [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 [c1 c2] [c1 c2]]
             [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 [c1 c2] [c1 c2]]] ``` I want this array

Comment: here `a1, a2, b1,b2, c1,c2` are integers. If i can't get that 3d array as output then I'll create two ind arrays one for a1, b1, c1 and and another for a2, b2, c2 and will get  two 2-d arrays using your method twice. So it's not a big problem

Comment: Please do **not** post sample in the comment. Update your question so that it is more readable, reproducible and reachable not just by an answerer, but by all others.

Comment: Thanks again @Chris One can think of replacing `a, b, c by [a1 a2], [b1 b2], [c1 c2] respectively` everywhere in my entire question to understand what I am asking. However my problem is solved using your code.